# Xdebug in PHP does not stop at breakpoint in intelliJ Idea

Tags: php, intellij-idea, xdebug, osx-elcapitan

Environment 
OS X El Capitan

```
➜  ~  php --version
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Nov 16 2015 16:28:23)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

IntelliJ IDE 13 setup

[image]

```
phpinfo();
```

[image]
[image]
listen to requests
[image]
[image]

The same setup used to work well (just hit the php url in browser and control stops at the break point of the code) but stopped working after I had to reinstall php53 using homebrew.

What could have could have gone wrong. Now var_dump() is the only way it seems.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of trial and error, it looks like the webserver was not listening to port 9000. I change the port to 9090 both at ext-xdebug.ini and IDE preference and restarted apache, it worked !

```
➜  ~   sudo lsof -i :9090
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   20822  daemon   22u  IPv4 0xead9c592a7139c1b      0t0  TCP localhost:49428->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
httpd   20822  daemon   23u  IPv4 0xead9c592ab5b9fbb      0t0  TCP localhost:49438->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
httpd   20822  daemon   26u  IPv4 0xead9c592aab3517b      0t0  TCP localhost:49436->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
httpd   20822  daemon   27u  IPv4 0xead9c592aa9224fb      0t0  TCP localhost:49440->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
httpd   20824  daemon   22u  IPv4 0xead9c592ab6406db      0t0  TCP localhost:49472->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
httpd   20824  daemon   23u  IPv4 0xead9c592ab640fbb      0t0  TCP localhost:49473->localhost:websm (CLOSED)
idea    21828 user1  287u  IPv4 0xead9c592afc6e33b      0t0  TCP *:websm (LISTEN)
```